# Total savings from monthly deposits

Tags: economics

If I add $\$1000$ to a bank account each month with the yearly interest of $2\%$ how much will I have in one year?

Answer says $\$12 111 $

I don't know how to get to that answer, can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Look up the [compound interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest) equation.  The first month collects interest for $11$ or $12$ periods depending on whether you make the deposit at the start or end of the month.  Each successive month draws interest for one less month.  It would be a good exercise to make a spreadsheet that tracks the balance every month, adding the new deposits and interest.  You will need that skill.  The interest multiplies the balance by $(1+\frac {0.02}{12})$ because the period is $\frac 1{12}$ year.

Comment: I tried it and I get 1000*(((1.02^12)-1)/1.02)*1.02 which is 13680.33.

not correct, I think I should use monthly interest rate actually which is 1.02/12 but then I just get (1.02/12)^12 in the equation, which seems like a dead end.

Comment: I gave you the factor for monthly interest in my answer.  It is neither of the ones you quote.  In your first you are giving $2\%$ interest per month.  In your second you are dividing the principle by $12$ as well as the interest.